# Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut to switch between Stage Manager window groups?

Tags: macos, stage-manager

Using Stage Manager, you can switch between windows in a single window group using <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>. However there seems to be no way using the keyboard to switch from one window group to the next. I would love to be able to do this. I like and use Stage Manager, but I think it's a little undercooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better Touch Tool lets you assign `Cycle through stages` actions that do that.

[image]

Comment: Not bad, I'll give that a try! I have used BTT in the past for other features.

Answer (score 0):

> there seems to be no way using the keyboard to switch from one window group to the next

That would defeat the purpose of [Stage Manager](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213315).

> Stage Manager organizes apps and windows so that your desktop is clutter-free and you can stay ***focused***.

The idea behind Stage Manager is to narrowly focus your attention on the work in front of you.  This is so designed that Apple included an option to show/hide items located on your Desktop!

Outside of stage manager, you can easily switch between windows across Spaces.  Stage Manager creates that “work silo” that allows you to focus.

**But, what if you need a window that’s not part of the group?**

Add it to the Stage Manager window group.

Comment: There is absolutely a use case for my request.

Comment: I’m describing how it functions, not that your use case is invalid.